# String To String Array With Multiple Conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, split

I have a bot which processes strings with given arguments. Here is what I've tried to get parameters of command:

```
parse: function (message, argLength) {
        var words = message.split(" ");
        words.shift(); // Don't return command name in array.
        if (words.length < argLength) // If there is not enough parameters, return null
            return null;
        else if (words.length == argLength) {   // If length is exact same, return     
            return words;
        }
        else { //Otherwise, concenate first ones till it is exact length.
            var concenateString = "";
            var length = words.length - argLength + 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                var element = words[0];
                concenateString += " " + element;
                words.shift();
            }
            words.unshift(concenateString);
            return words;
        }
    }
```

If there are more parameters than required, it will automatically concenate first strings since it is split by spaces. a b c with two parameters to "a b" "c" for example. But if `"`'s are passed, I want to get words between `"`'s, not only conceding first ones.

Comment: please add some examples of call and the wanted result of it.

Comment: Let's say I want two parameters; given parameters are "some multi" "word parameters". This code will parse it into an array like this: `["some multi word","parameters"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing any business logic you could use a regex to extract anything between `"` or words:

```js
var str = 'one two "three is family"'
var re = /"([^"]+)"|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g

console.log(
  str.match( re )
)
```

Comment: Will this return an array of strings?

Comment: try it I made a snippet

Comment: @maloman It is what I actually needed, thanks. I will accept this as the correct answer.